# Pegar parte do texto que está entre tags de uma String

Tags: string, vb.net

Tenho a seguinte string:

```
Meu nome é <nome> Nickolas Carlos<nome>
```

Queria saber como posso fazer em VB.NET para pegar somente o que está entre as tags `<nome>` que neste caso seria: `Nickolas Carlos`

É possivel fazer isso utilizando apenas VB.NET?

Comment: Não seria `<nome>` e `</nome>`?

Comment: Sim, pode ser também!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma opção usando regex:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Module VBModule
    Sub Main()
        Dim str As String = "Meu nome é <nome> Nickolas Carlos<nome>"
        Dim pad As New Regex("(?<=<nome> ).+(?=<nome>)")
        Dim nome As String = pad.Match(str).value
        Console.WriteLine(nome)
    End Sub
End Module
```

Só tenha cuidado com os espaços. Nesse caso, é considerando um espaço depois de `<nome>` e nenhum depois do nome.

Answer (score 1):

Uma possibilidade seria:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim minhaString = "Meu nome é <nome>Nicolas Carlos da Silva<nome>"
    Dim nome = minhaString.Substring(minhaString.IndexOf(">") + 1, minhaString.LastIndexOf("<") - minhaString.IndexOf(">") - 1)
    Debug.Print(nome)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Sei fazer isso em C#... mas acho que não terá problemas em converter pra VB.Net:

```
string texto = "xpto <nome> abc </nome>";
var match = Regex.Match(texto, @"\<nome\>\s*(.+?)\s*?\<\/nome\>");
var nome = match.Success ? match.Groups[1].Value : null;
```

O retorno será `abc` no exemplo acima.

A regex é eficiente pois uso os operadores `*?` e `+?` que tentam dar match primeiro nas alternativas menores ao invés das maiores primeiro (que seria o caso dos operadores `*` e `+`)